# I want to split this data into two columns one contains the first part of integer and one contain the second part chr

Tags: r

```
emp_no  first_name  age
10001   Georgi      55
10002   Bezalel     44
10003   Parto       52
10004   Chirstian   50
10005   Kyoichi     22
10006   Anneke      25
10007   Tzvetan     82
10008   Saniya      55y
10009   Sumant      5y
10010   Duangkaew   10y 8m
10011   Mary        44y
10012   Patricio    22y 8m
```

Comment: Please show your expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::separate`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(age = gsub("[A-Za-z]", "", age)) %>% 
  separate(age, into = c("year", "month"))

   emp_no first_name year month
1   10001     Georgi   55  <NA>
2   10002    Bezalel   44  <NA>
3   10003      Parto   52  <NA>
4   10004  Chirstian   50  <NA>
5   10005    Kyoichi   22  <NA>
6   10006     Anneke   25  <NA>
7   10007    Tzvetan   82  <NA>
8   10008     Saniya   55  <NA>
9   10009     Sumant    5  <NA>
10  10010  Duangkaew   10     8
11  10011       Mary   44  <NA>
12  10012   Patricio   22     8
```

Comment: You may also use `extract` `df1 %>% extract(age, into = c("year", "month"), "^(\\d+)[^0-9]*(\\d+)?", convert = TRUE)`